# Is `git` a command in Windows cmd environment?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Assuming I have git installed, does it make `git` a command in Windows cmd environment? Why is it not in the output list when I run `help`? And same question for `ping` command. Thank you

Comment: `git` isn't native windows's program. If you want it would be accessible from console everywhere you need to set in environment variable `PATH` to location where you installed `git` program. Here is info, how to set it up: https://www.howtogeek.com/51807/how-to-create-and-use-global-system-environment-variables/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as %PATH% lists a directory which contains `git.exe` (or git.bat, git.cmd, git.com…), it will be available as a command in both cmd.exe and PowerShell.

The Git for Windows installer asks you whether the directory containing git.exe should be added to %PATH%. You can also do this manually. There are no other steps required to "define" something as a command.

Running `help` in Windows' cmd.exe shows a *hardcoded* list of commands (most of which hasn't changed since MS-DOS era), but does not actually enumerate all commands available in %PATH%. You can ignore this list.